# Mysql filter on one condition and then filter on different conditon

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a mysql table called `data_tbl` that has bunch of rows with different ids as follows

```
-----------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
id   | date       | user | field               | change_from | change_to
-----------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
7293 | 08/29/2017 | chey | Status              | M           | R        
7293 | 08/29/2017 | chey | File Name           |             | Diffs-com
7293 | 08/29/2017 | chey | Status              | V           | M        
7293 | 08/07/2017 | chey | Note Title          |             | static-an
2293 | 08/07/2017 | chey | File Name           |             | Diffs-com
7293 | 06/28/2017 | dets | Is-customer-visible | N           | Y        
7293 | 05/30/2017 | unmx | Status              | R           | V        
2293 | 05/24/2017 | chey | Bug-origin          |             | Code / Im
3593 | 05/24/2017 | chey | Regression          |             | N        
7293 | 05/24/2017 | chey | Status              | A           | R        
3293 | 05/24/2017 | chey | Note Title          |             | static-an
4293 | 05/24/2017 | chey | File Name           |             | Diffs-com
4293 | 05/24/2017 | chey | File Name           |             | Diffs-com
5293 | 05/22/2017 | chey | Note Title          |             | static-an
7293 | 05/22/2017 | chey | File Name           |             | Diffs-com
7293 | 04/28/2017 | gogi | Engineer            | gogi        | chey     
7293 | 04/25/2017 | dets | Is-customer-visible |             | N        
7293 | 04/25/2017 | itka | Assigner            |             | itka     
7293 | 04/25/2017 | itka | Engineer            |             | gogi     
7293 | 04/25/2017 | itka | Status              | N           | A        
7093 | 04/25/2017 | koga | Defect Created      |             |          
7393 | 04/25/2017 | vkal | Defect Created      |             |          
7293 | 04/25/2017 | vkal | Defect Created      |             |          
7293 | 04/25/2017 | vkal | Defect Created      |             |          
7293 | 04/25/2017 | vkal | Defect Created      |             |          
-----------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
```

from the above table how can i write a query that filters within itself as follows

```
select * from data_tbl where id in ('7293', '7093') and 
(from the filtered rows from above, filter when field is "engineer" change_to must be "chey" and when field is status change_from should be "A" and change_to should be "R")
```

my goal is to filter the data set from above and get something like the following

```
-----------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
id   | date       | user | field               | change_from | change_to
-----------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+

7293 | 05/24/2017 | chey | Status              | A           | R        
7293 | 04/28/2017 | gogi | Engineer            | gogi        | chey     
-----------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I tested all the answers and was able to get the data sub set i want. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this as the description

> 1. `where id in ('7293', '7093') AND`
> 2. ... `when field is "engineer" ... change_to must be "chey" OR ...`
> 3. ...  `when field is status ... change_from should be "A" and change_to should be "R")`

The SQL becomes:

```
 select * from data_tbl where id in ('7293', '7093') 
  AND (
   (field = 'Engineer' AND change_to = 'chey') OR
   (field = 'Status' AND change_from = 'A' AND change_to = 'R') 
  );
```

Comment: i ended up using this and was able to convert this into SQL alchemy, thank you for that

Answer (score 1):

Your condition

> 1. when field is "engineer" change_to must be "chey"
> 2. when field is status change_from should be "A" and change_to should be "R"

You might use `UNION` combine two selects query.

```
SELECT ID,DATE,USER,field,change_from,change_to 
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,DATE,USER,field,change_from,change_to
    FROM data_tbl
    WHERE change_from = 'A' AND change_to = 'R'
    UNION
    SELECT ID,DATE,USER,field,change_from,change_to
    FROM data_tbl
    WHERE field = 'engineer' AND change_to = 'chey'
) AS A
WHERE A.ID in ('7293', '7093')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements and desired result what you need is just a `select` statement with some filters and `case` statements to generate the desired data:

```
SELECT id, date, user, field, 
       CASE WHEN field = 'Status' THEN 'A'
            ELSE change_from 
        END change_from
       CASE WHEN field = 'Engineer' THEN 'chey' 
            WHEN field = 'Status' THEN 'R'
            ELSE change_to 
        END change_to
 WHERE id IN ('7293', '7093')
   AND field IN ('Engineer', 'Status');
```

This will yield exactly as the result you added as desired. Based of course in the provided sample data.

Answer (score 1):

These are just filters, except that when you say "When this... and (instead) when that...", that "and" is actually a logical OR, because you want both conditions to be acceptable.

> *filter when field is "engineer" change_to must be "chey"*

```
((`field` = 'Engineer' AND change_to = 'chey')
```

> *and when field is status change_from should be "A" and change_to should be "R"*

```
(`field` = 'Status' AND change_from = 'A' AND change_to = 'R'))
```

So:

```
WHERE id IN (7093, 7293)
AND
(
    (`field` = 'Engineer' AND change_to = 'chey')
    OR
    (`field` = 'Status' AND change_from = 'A' AND change_to = 'R')
)
```

If you want to have those Status and Engineer lines, but also the others (e.g. Regression, Assigner, ...), if these last are few, you can name them explicitly:

```
    ...
    OR
    (`field` = 'Status' AND change_from = 'A' AND change_to = 'R')
    OR
    (`field` = 'Assigner')
    OR
    (`field` = 'Note Taken')
```

If, on the other hand, there are many types, you'd be better served by specifying "others": records with field that are neither Statud nor Engineer.

```
    ...
    OR
    (`field` = 'Status' AND change_from = 'A' AND change_to = 'R')
    OR
    (`field` NOT IN ('Status', 'Engineer'))
```